# Reading from buffer shows unrecognizable (Chinese) characters

Tags: c#, pinvoke, apimonitor

I am doing a `P/Invoke` on `Ntdll.dll!NtWriteFile` and while reading the Buffer `(PVOID)`, I'm getting unrecognizable characters. I tried different encoding with no change. I'm also monitoring the process using API Monitor from `Rohitab` so I see the correct value I'm trying to retrieve. Anyone run into this issue?

```
NtWriteFile(
  IN HANDLE  FileHandle,
  IN HANDLE  Event OPTIONAL,
  IN PIO_APC_ROUTINE      ApcRoutine OPTIONAL,
  IN PVOID ApcContext OPTIONAL,
  OUT PIO_STATUS_BLOCK    IoStatusBlock,
  IN PVOID Buffer,
  IN ULONG Length,
  IN PLARGE_INTEGER ByteOffset OPTIONAL,
  IN PULONG  Key OPTIONAL );
```

Example of output:

> 笍^稌ƭ덾塾畿浽ꭼɿݾ浼굺ꥻꥻ Āጀ‘℀
>
> 萰퓶픊茚  缊<縌੾葿繾륿뙾孿퍿Ϳ큾靾≿≿
>
> 缊f縌ϲ橿⹿筿偿᱿㽿ꅿ왿ѿ豿豿 笍^稌ƭ덾塾畿浽ꭼɿݾ浼굺ꥻꥻ 缊<縌੾葿繾륿뙾孿퍿Ϳ큾靾≿≿
>   缊f縌ϲ橿⹿筿偿᱿㽿ꅿ왿ѿ豿豿 缷舆ⴀᣢ

Comment: Is it possible that it is some kind of error message in Chinese? I've put it into Bing translate, it makes mention of 'unloading' and 'computer service', granted it's still a large mess however.

Comment: Instead of looking at characters it would probably be better to look at bytes, can you post some of those?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I was able to encode the text by using the below.

```
Byte[] bytes = Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(p);
var bUTF8 = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(bytes);
```

Comment: Please can you explain how this answers the question that you asked? Nowhere in the question is there an C# string p. Nowhere is there any mention of UTF8. The code in your answer has to be wrong. It is clear that you have put 8 bit text into a C# string and interpreted it is UTF-16. And the code here is a crass and bogus way to get around that mistake. Decode the original bytes as 8 bit and all will be well. But it doesn't look as though you are trying to learn.

Comment: That the code you show here appears to help confirms the first sentence in my answer. Pass the original byte array to `Encoding.UTF8.GetString()` or `Encoding.Ansi.GetString()` or whichever 8 bit encoding was used. Don't do whatever you do to put the 8 bit byte array directly into `p`.

Answer (score 1):

That's what happens when you interpret ASCII or ANSII encoded text as if it were UTF-16. So, you need to find out what the text encoding really is, and interpret it accordingly.

So perhaps whatever it is you are using to inspect the data is using UTF-16 by mistake. Or, maybe more likely, your code that writes should be writing UTF-16.